# How deep could a human swim with SCUBA apparatus?

Tags: human-physiology, environment

Using normal SCUBA apparatus and wet suit, how much pressure can the human body withstand? This is assuming that they descend as gradually as necessary for their body to make adjustments. What would be first symptoms that they experience as they descend? And if they descend to the deepest depth that they can reach without immediate permanent harm, how long can they spend at that depth before time related symptoms set in?

Comment: It's not a question that has a simple answer.  Do you mean diving with simple compressed air?  Then 130 ft/39 m is the accepted max for recreational divers.  With different air mixes, you can go much deeper.  The other problem is not going deep, though, it's coming back up.  Gas dissolves in the blood at high pressure, and if you come up too fast makes bubbles, AKA "the bends", which can be fatal.  All this and more can be found in the Wikipedia article ttps://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_diving or through a simple search.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can find the current world record for "[scuba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scuba_diving)" diving is [1,090 ft 4.5 in](http://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/news/2014/9/ahmed-gabr-breaks-record-for-deepest-scuba-dive-at-more-than-1000-feet-60537/) set in 2014.

The previous record was 1,044 ft set in 2005 so (as with most human endurance & physical achievement records nowadays) we're most likely at the limit of the possible there.

Barring a few more feet (or even just inches) of course.

Howsoever, that's only normal scuba diving equipment

[Deep diving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_diving) using [hydrox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrox_(breathing_gas)) and [trimix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trimix_(breathing_gas)) has reached depths of 1,644 ft (1977) & 1,752 ft (1988).

So the answer depends on if you're asking about with normal commercial scuba gear using bog standard compressed air or if you want to include breathing mixes etc to help alleviate [the bends](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decompression_sickness).